# python: c and fortran ordering of same numpy array; timing analysis

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

I stored a numpy array of dimension (10000,10000) in c-order and fortran-order. Performed similar operations on these arrays to see which one is faster/slow.

**Before executing the python script, my conclusion is:
array stored in c-order should be faster than array stored in fortran-order (for the same loop (first loop over rows and then loop over columns)) **

But I got the opposite result for one case (out of many positive results); below is the

```
output of the code:

calculation for C style array
  C_CONTIGUOUS : True
  F_CONTIGUOUS : False
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

(10000, 10000)
time taken in sec: -403.6266212463379
same calculation for fortran style array
  C_CONTIGUOUS : False
  F_CONTIGUOUS : True
  OWNDATA : True
  WRITEABLE : True
  ALIGNED : True
  WRITEBACKIFCOPY : False
  UPDATEIFCOPY : False

(10000, 10000)
time taken in sec: -368.0309956073761
```

Here is my python code:

```
# coding: utf-8
import numpy as np
import time 

nrow=10000
ncol=10000

print ('calculation for C style array')
#nrow=1000
#ncol=1000
arr = np.linspace(-1,1,nrow*ncol).reshape(nrow,ncol)
yf = np.array(arr, order='C')
print(yf.flags)
print(np.shape(yf))
start = time.time()
for row in range(nrow):
    for col in range(ncol):
        #print (yf[row, col])
        a=((yf[row, col]+yf[row,col]**10)/yf[row, col] * yf[row, col])
        b=a**2 + a**3  +a**10
        #with open('cstyle.dat','w') as f:
        #    f.write(str(b))
end = time.time()
print('time taken in sec: {}'.format(start-end))



print ('same calculation for fortran style array')
#nrow=1000
#ncol=1000
arr = np.linspace(-1,1,nrow*ncol).reshape(nrow,ncol)
yf = np.array(arr, order='F')
print(yf.flags)
print(np.shape(yf))
start = time.time()
for row in range(nrow):
    for col in range(ncol):
        #print (yf[row, col])
        a=((yf[row, col]+yf[row,col]**10)/yf[row, col] * yf[row, col])
        b=a**2 + a**3  +a**10
        #with open('fstyle.dat','w') as f:
        #    f.write(str(b))
end = time.time()
print('time taken in sec: {}'.format(start-end))
#print(start-end)
```

So: 
1) why the opposite results?
2) why the timing is always different if I run the same code multiple times?

Comment: The time is always different because it not only depends on your code, it also depends on the SO, how is the memory & the cache in that momment, if there are another tasks the system is doing, etc.

Comment: @nacho Yes, i agree with you that other tasks might alter the timing when same code is run multiple times (during which some low and heavy jobs are running concurrently). But, does above result means that c and fortran ordering are not important!!

Comment: Others have found that order doesn't make a big difference. The strided approach to storage handles both orders well. BUT your iterative code doesn't make good use of either order. `a=yf +yf**10/...`

Comment: @hpaulj : could you please elaborate in detail? I don't' get your point.

Comment: The order of the array is really important when the array is big enough. The problem is that you should try multiple times and then use the average times. One only result doesn't mean anything just because there could be a lot of system jobs & tasks (or none of them) in that momment

Comment: And the results may be different because numpy doesn't store your array in a contiguos memory block. If you want to get better results, your need to use **yf = np.ascontiguousarray(arr)** for the C style array and  **yf = np.asfortranarray(arr)** for the fortran style array

Comment: @nacho both np.ascontiguousarray(arr) and np.array(arr, ordrer="c') does the same job. So, I think it will not affect the results significantly. See link : . Also, I need to run multiple times to find the timing. Thanks!